# Wordpress custom save button in post type says: are you sure you leave this page?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, submit-button

I've created a custom post type with meta box, at the end I put a button to save changes

```
<?php submit_button( 'Controlla ora', 'primary', 'controlla_button' );?>
```

If a make a change when I press the button,a popup appear : "are you sure you leave this page?"

Is there a way to use this button like "save draft" ? I mean without the popup?

Thanks-

Answer (score -1):

Solved:

```
<input type="button" id="controlla_button" class="button button-primary" onclick="change_s()" value="Controlla ora" >

<script type="text/javascript">
     function change_s(){
document.getElementById("publish").click();
}     
</script>
```